# what versions of android lets you share saved wifi using qr code?

Tags: wi-fi, qr-code

i am trying to list the versions that support sharing saved wifi through qr code .

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of the upcoming Android Q version.

There are device manufacturers who have already implemented this feature in their current Android 9 devices (e.g. Huawei).

Comment: can i get a refer ?

Comment: I have not found an official announcement by Google, but if you search for `android wifi qr share` you are getting plenty of sources from news sites. The fact that Huawei already has this feature I got from a German print news magazine.

Comment: I searched that but all what I found was apps .. I asked some people and have found that is there on these models Huawei Y7 Prime android 8 

xiaomi note 6 android 8 / 8.1
Xiaomi Mi 9 android 9
Xiaomi Note5    8 / 8.1            and many more I think . where do you think I can get more info ... And there is another question on xiaomi you have to be currently connected to that network to be able to share the qr code .. And you can't do it on just  saved WiFi networks .

Comment: Just use one of the following articles: [Q 1](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/03/13/android-q-lets-you-share-and-connect-to-wifi-networks-with-qr-codes/) [Q 2](https://www.androidauthority.com/android-q-wifi-qr-code-965569/) [Q 3](https://wccftech.com/android-q-allows-users-to-share-wifi-networks-via-qr-codes-gets-a-new-files-app-and-more/) [Samsung](https://www.sammobile.com/2019/08/06/how-to-share-wi-fi-networks-using-qr-code-on-one-ui-android-pie/)

Comment: Yup ... the other phones brands that doesn't have android Q added it based on the manufacture UI .