# Open Wifi QR code on Android 8

Tags: wi-fi, 8.1-oreo, qr-code

I have an old Wileyfox 2x with Android 8.1 on it.

When I try to open a 'WiFi QR code', instead of creating a new WiFi connection, the pseudo-URL is just opened in a browser window.

Is this even possible on Android 8, and if so, do I maybe need another scanner app? I'm using Firefox's built-in scanner now, but perhaps that only supports http links?

If it's not supported by Android natively, are there other ways of opening such a code? Could this be done by an app?

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215776/what-versions-of-android-lets-you-share-saved-wifi-using-qr-code

Comment: @rockpaperlz-mask-it-or-casket I had found that question, but it isn't clear to me if it's about *opening* a QR code, or *generating* one.

Comment: How QR will be handled depends on the app, so there's a big possibility that Firefox's built-in scanner only supports for browsing. Try another app like [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android) which is possibly one of the most popular barcode scanner apps for general purpose on Android.

Comment: @andrewt Thanks, that app works perfect, the Wifi connection is made and the AP's login page is opened. Out of curiosity I'd still like to know if this is something completely done by the scanner app, or that some level of support from Android is required.

Comment: In addition to the barcode/QR code scanner that Andrew mentioned, if you're interested in an open-source solution, you can also try the excellent SecScanQR: https://f-droid.org/packages/de.t_dankworth.secscanqr/   I have not tested it for this particular use, but if you try it for this purpose, let us know if it works!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I tried seqscanqr, but it doesn't support this particular kind of action. It shows a textual representation of the WIFI: pseudo URL but does not provide an option to connect to the network. BTW Barcode Scanner is open source too (Apache 2 license), but does not seem to be actively developed anymore.

Comment: @Berend Thank you so very much for the update.  It's much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, here's my own answer, thanks to @andrew-t.

It looks as though parsing a Wifi QR code is not something provided by Android, at least not in version 8.1.

The [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android) app does recognize the type of QR code, and opens the login page for the Access Point.